# Are there ways to get android app view hierarchy from another android app?

Tags: android, ui-automation

I'm researching ways to do android automation running on the device, without any workstation connection.

My approach is like this, i modified monkey's source, and is able to start 3rd party app (which i don't have the source access), I can send the keystrokes to the app too. But now I'm facing another problem, i need access properties of some ui elements, for e.g. get button's text for verification purpose.

How can i get the system's (or top activity's) hierarchy from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to accomplish this.

Comment: but how did adbd accomplish this? as far as i know, I can connect hierarchyviewer to my rooted device. Can i use JNI to call the same method adbd calls? In my scenario, the automation tests only run on rooted device, i think i got enough permission to do anything, excepts changing the android system.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, check out Robotium here: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/
It is open source, so you should be able to check out how they do it.

You don't need access to sources of the target app.

Comment: Looks like it's not right. Robotium can access only same app and app under test (it uses WindowManager instance to get views). Could you specify what exactly 'they do'?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking at the hierarchy with this:

https://madcoda.com/2013/01/inspect-the-view-hierarchy-of-any-android-app/
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

And then writing the code with the use of the Accessibility class to access it.
http://www.apps4android.org/?p=3628